# Upload image by clearing previous image

Tags: python, tkinter

so i have this simple app to upload image but now i want every time i upload a new image, the previous image get cleared. Looking for the solution, thanks in advance.

```
def open():
    global my_image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="e:/images", title="Select A File",
                                               filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    my_image_label = Label(image=my_image).pack()


my_btn = Button(root, text="Open File", command=open).pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the labels outside the function and update it inside the function, this will avoid over-writing the labels with new data each time. Take a look here:

```
# Define the labels initially
my_image_label = Label(root) 
my_label = Label(root)

def open_img():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="e:/images", title="Select A File",
                                               filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    my_label.config(text=path) # Update the label with the path
    my_label.pack() # Pack it in there

    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=path) # Make an ImageTk instance
    my_image_label.config(image=my_image) # Update the image label
    my_image_label.pack() # Pack the label
    my_image_label.img = my_img # Keep reference to the image

my_btn = Button(root, text="Open File", command=open_img)
my_btn.pack()
```

**What all have I changed?**

- I used the `config()` method of widgets helps you to edit the options of the widgets.
- I have also removed the usage of `Image.open()` as you can achieve the same by using `file` keyword argument of `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, it calls `Image.open()` implicitly.
- Also I removed `global` and kept a reference to the image.
- I also renamed some variables and changed the name of you're function, as `open()` will over ride the built-in `open()` function of python.

Comment: Is it ok to use `open` as the name of the function?

Comment: @JacksonPro Nope that will clearly over-ride the built in `open()`. Thanks for pointing it out, edited.